# I am getting a key error how to get rid of this

Tags: python, cgi

I am new to python programming and I was reading [the headfirst python book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Yvox.png). I wrote the correct code but it is not working why?

```
import cgi

form_data = cgi.FieldStorage()
```

The following line gives an error:

```
  athlete_name = form_data['Which_Athelete']
```

and the Error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Hamza Shah/Desktop/Headfirst Python/chapter7/webapp/cgi-bin/generate_timing_data.py", line 7, in <module>
    athlete_name = form_data['Which_Athelete']
  File "C:\Users\Hamza Shah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\cgi.py", line 534, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'Which_Athelete'
```

Comment: ... because you haven't submitted a form containing a field with the name "Which_Athelete'?

Comment: @DanielRoseman how to submit a form? I am new to python and web programming

Comment: But what are you trying to do? Why are you trying to get that key in the first place?

Comment: and where to submit the form ?

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do. But you can go through some of the online material like  http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/06/08/python-101-how-to-submit-a-web-form/

Comment: Why don't you carry on reading the book, until you find the explanations of all this?

Comment: @DanielRoseman sir there is no explanation that's why I came here

Comment: Have you tried a lower cased version of `Which_Athlete`? The screenshot you provided has it in a lower case.

Comment: i tried it but not working .

Comment: try: athlete_name = form_data['which_athlete'].value
You are using upper case in key when the image has everything in lower case. Additionally you have misspelt "athlete" as "athelete".

Answer (score 0):

The output of the following code is

```
    FieldStorage(None, None, [])
```

There is No key named Which_Athlete in there. Therefore this is giving you an error

Comment: yes I know but I am adding a key Which_athlete then why it gives me error

Comment: please see the picture I attached it

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to check "if the key exists", so no matter what if you submit the key in the form, or submit a form at all, the code won't fail.

In older Python versions you would do that with `has_key` but in newer Python you would use `in`.

Since the data returned by `cgi.FieldStorage()` is nothing but a dictionary (in other languages this is commonly known as an array), you can do this:

```
form_data = cgi.FieldStorage()
if 'your_key' in form_data:
    # do your things here
```

Previously with older Python you would have done this:

```
form_data = cgi.FieldStorage()
if dictionary.has_key('keyname'):
    # do your things here
```

Read more on https://portingguide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dicts.html

Hope this helps, and good luck with Python!